# Chrome extension change border-radius and position

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I add `border-radius` on chrome extension popup?
Also, can I add something like `margin-top` to the popup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the answer from chromium developer:

> Alas, that's not something you can control. Your popup content is
>   basically an iframe inside a window - you can't control the host
>   window

Answer (score 5):

Chrome simply doesn't allow that.
Alternatives are, instead of the popup, opening a new window or injecting a content script in the active tab to display a modal.